# selections validation by value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 select fields with `id's id1, id2,.. id5`
and i need check if values (selected) not equal then highlight green and if equal then highlight red
but is look crazy validate each field 5 times? is posible use special functions ir validate easy than with:

```
if
  if 
    if
      if
```

I dont need a code just idea.

Comment: Why dont u try for-loop in select fields?

Comment: if selected value in id1 not equal with id2, id3.. id5 if id2 not equal with id1 id3 etc

Comment: If I understand well, you want to validate that your 5 fields all have different selected values ?

Comment: @Bartdude YES different

Comment: then you just need to try with a loop if you don't want to write several `if` statements or a long one with many `AND`'s and `OR`'s. Try using a for loop then come back if you get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each select to compare the values

```
$("select").change(function () {
    flag = false;
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("select").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != value)
            flag = true;
    });
    if (flag)
        $("select").css("color", "red");
    else
        $("select").css("color", "green");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uk3E3/8/)

**Edit**

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var flag = true;
    $("select").each(function () {
        var outer = this;
        $("select").not(outer).each(function () {
            if ($(outer).val() == $(this).val()) {
                flag = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
    if (flag)
        $("select").css("color", "green");
    else
        $("select").css("color", "red");

});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uk3E3/22/)

**New update**

I've simplified the code like this. YOu dont have to use nested loop if you do like this

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var flag = true;
    $("select").each(function () {
        if ($("select").find("option:selected[value=" + this.value + "]").length > 1) {
            flag = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (flag)
        $("select").css("color", "green");
    else
        $("select").css("color", "red");
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uk3E3/23/)

Comment: this function awesome for me. But if values are 1-1-1-1-1 than red but if 1-2-1-1-1 green should be red. green just then 1-2-3-4-5

Comment: sorry i didnt get you. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: ? how? i dont know how to improve this function

Comment: I mean, can you elaborate more about the need

Comment: I want to check if values in select menu is not equal than highlight green if egual than red exmp values 1-2-3-4-5 is green but 1-2-3-4-4 or 1-1-1-1-1 or 1-1-2-1-1 is red

Comment: @user3747585 see the updated answer.. Dot forget to accept it, if it worked for you. :)

Comment: How to exept Please select. If i have 5 select and by default values is Please select how to validate values with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var selected    =   []; 
    var valiSel     =   [];

    $('select > option:selected').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != 0){
            selected.push( $(this).val() );
        }
        valiSel.push( $(this).val() );

    });
    var unique = unique12(selected);
    var uniqueLength = unique.length;   
    var valiSelUnique = unique12(valiSel);  
    var selectedLength = selected.length;   

    if(  unique.length !=  selected.length ){
    alert( 'Two Selected value cannot be same' );
    return false;
    }       

    //return true;

});

function unique12(sel) {
    var r = new Array();
    o:for(var i = 0, n = sel.length; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0, y = r.length; x < y; x++)
        {
                if(r[x]==sel[i])
                {
                //alert('this is a DUPE!');
                        continue o;
                }
        }
        r[r.length] = sel[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uk3E3/11/)